# What is an official property or value to size a div container to it's content?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Is there an official property or value you can set on a div to have it size to it's content? You would think that `height:auto` would do it but it doesn't.

If one does not exist than that's a valid answer.

I've searched on https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss but could not find a reference to auto sizing a div. Someone's searching may have better results.

There's other questions that try and answer the question but it's not a how to question it's a link me to an official documentation describing a property, value or behavior.

Comment: That's not how CSS or W3C specs in general work. There's no such property, but you'll never find something in a spec saying that explicitly because it would preclude such a feature being added in the future. The specs are written such that new features can be added without directly contradicting the specs that have gone before.

Comment: Thanks to the answers below I've followed links to official `fit to content` values `fit-content`, `fit-available`, `max-content` and `min-content`. I'm still reading about them and how they are supposed to work. More info here https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box-3/#propdef-height.

Comment: fit-content etc still don't include absolutely positioned descendants.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is. If you use absolute or fixed positioned elements in your container its no surprise it isnt working.
You should supply an example.
An other option would be using `display: inline-block;` which can cause some problems, depending on your markup and other elements.

Comment: I have another question that has a link to code example. But I'm looking for specific official documentation. I'd like to read something from Mozilla or Google on how to tell a container to size to it's content. I doubt it exists. I doubt they have ever written a page or specified a property that creates this behavior.

Comment: As I mentoined, the question is how the children of the container are styled. And actually there is documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). 
Further reading [Visual formatting model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Visual_formatting_model)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/height.

There are some experimental new values that may do: `min-content` and `fit-content`. Of course, those are experimental and should not be used on production code yet without a proper fallback.

Comment: That might be the answer. I found it linking to https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box-3/#propdef-height where there are recommendations on getting this behavior.

Comment: I must repeat to you that those values currently only work on Chrome browser (desktop and Android). For other browsers you must use a fallback solution.